# Is there any way to impersonate user with administrative privileges without providing password on windows via python?

Tags: python, windows, impersonation, pywin32

I need to write script which should install/run/stop/update/remove windows services - that requires admin's privileges. I want to do that in python, then build it to .exe using py2exe.
I've done some research and I've found many pages with similar examples to this one: http://docs.activestate.com/activepython/2.5/pywin32/Windows_NT_Security_.2d.2d_Impersonation.html

Is there any way to impersonate user with administrative privileges without providing his password? I mean, after running a script, program should ask a user for permission with popup window: "Do you want the following program to allow changes to this computer?".

Comment: Are you saying you want the user to authorize the program (probably with an admin password) instead of bundling the password with the script, or are you saying you want to use admin privileges without any sort of password being involved at runtime?

Comment: Yes, I want to use admin priviliges without any sort of password being involved at runtime - exactly. I just want user to click "Yes" when he sees popup "Do you want to allow the following program to make changes to your computer?"

Comment: Is the user running this supposed to have admin privileges? You're going to need authorization by someone with admin privileges at some point in the process.

Comment: Yes, user should have admins privileges. But the question is: could it happen without actually typing a password?

Comment: Why do you need to impersonate anyone, then? You need admin privileges. You're running as a user with admin privileges. You have what you need.

Comment: Maybe little misunderstanding. I meant user should be able to "Click" yes on mentioned popup. Right now user has to click with right mouse button on the script icon and choose "Run as Administrator" and then confirm by clicking "yes" on popup. My goal is to avoid this situation. I want user to run the script just by double clicking on it's icon, and then script should somehow induce the popup with confirmation about admin privileges. I thought it might be possible by impersonation...

Comment: Sounds like your question is "how do I make a python script ask for elevation?"

Comment: Actually I've done it some way: at the beginning the script check if user has admin privileges - if not, it run itself again using win32api.ShellExecute with "runas" option enabled. But it is not really elegant idea I believe. Now I'm looking for more appropriate way to do that. Impersonation?